# Why is my static_cast of a pointer failing?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why is my static_cast of a pointer failing?

```
int iDog = 456;
int *piDog = &iDog;
long *plDog = static_cast<long*>(piDog); // invalid type conversion

long lDog = static_cast<long>(iDog);    // ok

long* plDog = (long*)(piDog); // this is OK too... very weird!! (Dynamic cast... and we aren't allowed to use this one in our coding standards)
```

This reference suggests it should be OK:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

Issue with Visual Studio C++?

Comment: Hint: `sizeof(long) != sizeof(int)`. `piDog` isn't large enough to hold a `long`.

Comment: @tadman But they're both pointer-types, and (usually) `sizeof(long*) == sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: They are both pointer types, but they are different types of pointers and not compatible types.

Comment: @Dai The pointers have an identical size, but the data they point to does not. De-referencing `plDog` is probably undefined behaviour, the memory footprint of `iDog` is too small for a `long`.

Comment: As far as the standard is concerned, I don't believe it really even matters if they are the same size, it's still wrong.

Comment: Right - I know you'd use `reinterpret_cast` instead.

Comment: `sizeof(long) == 4` with both the 32-bit and 64-bit compiler on Visual C++.  However, that static_cast is still not a safe expression.  You could use `reinterpret_cast` provided that you `static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not meant for type-punning.  In my experience, most cases I've come across where `reinterpret_cast` is used, undefined behavior follows.

Comment: How does that reference suggest it is OK? Amazing that you think Visual Studio would be getting such a trivial piece of code wrong. Use `reinterpret_cast` instead.

Comment: The size of the underlying data types is not an issue here, even casting `char*` to `unsigned char*` requires `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: `(long*)(piDog);` - this C-style-cast is not neccesarily OK, it simply forces the compiler to do the cast. Most likely UB will follow. That's why C++ introduced other, safer casts.

Comment: The reference you link to has 10 points specifying allowed casts. That leaves a lot of guesswork to the reader. Perhaps you could edit your question and add an explanation of which point you believe applies and why it applies?

Comment: `(long*)` is casting by the Hammer of God. No matter how bad, stupid, or insane the conversion is a C-Style cast will make it happen. My rule of thumb when I see one of these babies is to investigate the code more closely for the bug it's hiding.

Comment: *"this is OK too... very weird"* -- not weird, but apparently you have not consulted your reference (cppreference) for [explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)? The things allowed by static cast fall under 1.b), so you have not considered 1.a,c, d, and e?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** If your cast worked, the language would provide no type-safety guarantees for pointers, and is a key part of the motivation for introducing the C++ style casts instead of sticking with the old-school C cast.

In the language of the C/C++ Standard, `long*` and `int*` are not "pointer-compatible". You can't implicitly convert a `long*` to an `int*` or vice-versa, so `static_cast` can't do it in a single cast.

> The reasoning behind that is `sizeof(long)` is not always equal to `sizeof(int)` for all platforms. They are distinct fundamental types. This is true in general of all distinct C/C++ types even if they have an identical binary layout. They are only "pointer-compatible" if in the syntax of the language you declare the types to be related via implicit conversion.

You can use `static_cast` when converting from a `void*` to any pointer to an object type or vice-versa.

Therefore you can do this in two ways:

- `reinterpret_cast<long*>(piDog);`

-or-

- `static_cast<long*>(static_cast<void*>(piDog));`

Stylistically, the use of the `reinterpret_cast` is a lot clearer. In either case, the validity of the cast is architecture dependent and assumes `sizeof(int)` == `sizeof(long)` as well as having the same memory layout.

> IOW This is safe for Windows x86 and x64 native, but may not hold for other platforms or CPUs. This is one of the reasons Windows x64 choose to use the [LLP64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) data model as explained in [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050131-00/?p=36563).

See cppreference for [static_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) and [reinterpret_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

Comment: Whether or not `int` and `long` have the same size is irrelevant; the types are *unrelated* (one is not derived from the other), and a `static_cast` is not allowed between pointers to unrelated types.

Comment: Sure they are not 'pointer compatible' in the language of the standard. I was trying to address the OP's comment "But they're both pointer-types, and (usually) sizeof(long*) == sizeof(int*). "

Comment: The first answer was a bit rough, so tried cleaning it up a bit...

Comment: Meh. I think you've missed the point - which is that the OP is trying to cast *pointers* rather than plain `int` and `long` data types. You could `typedef` two ***identical*** `struct` types and *still* the `static_cast` between their pointers would be invalid

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> long *plDog = static_cast<long*>(piDog); // invalid type conversion
> ```
>
> Why is my static_cast of a pointer failing?

Because it is ill-formed. None of the rules of static_cast apply to the cast that you're attempting. It is an invalid conversion, as you mention in the comments.

A pointer to one object type may not be static casted to a pointer to another object type unless they are pointers to related classes, or when casting to/from pointer to void.

> This reference suggests it should be OK: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

That reference suggests that the conversion you attempt is **not OK**.

> ```
> long* plDog = (long*)(piDog); // this is OK too... very weird!!
> ```

This is a well-formed conversion. It's not "weird".

There are many conversions that explicit conversions (also called "cast notation" or "C-style cast") allow, and static casts do not allow. This is because static casts have (at least a semblance of) type safety while explicit conversions essentially ask the compiler to pretend that the type system doesn't exist.

Note that indirecting through `plDog` and accessing the object would result in undefined behaviour. As you can see, it was a good thing that you got the error.

> and we aren't allowed to use this one in our coding standards

This is a good limitation to have. This will make it bit harder for your team to write bugs by mistakenly circumventing the type system.

> Issue with Visual Studio C++?

No, the issue is that the program is ill-formed. The compiler is correct to inform you about the bug, and is not required to compile the program.

---

I recommend asking yourself: Why do you want to, or think that you need to do such cast?